# How crypt in dephi like PHP openssl_encrypt($message, "aes-128-ecb",

Tags: php, delphi, aes, crypt

I have next 2 PHP function for crypt and decrypt.
They works fine.

```
<Results are:
AbvmAYxQAhQOPF50UZLj9bc
4162766d415978514168514f50463530555a4c6a396263
LR12;15;41e33b9
```

My problem:
I must create crypt function in delphi and decode in PHP.
I try use:

1. TDCP_rijndael: not exists ecb property.
2. Turbopower Lockbox3 - property AdvancedOptions2.optOpenSSL_CompatiblityMode:= Tue; -->
   Error "Advanced option still in develpment and not yet avalaible".
3. OpenSSL260 package demo, EldoS, Alexander Ionov  ElAES.pas, FlyUtils.AES.... -> dont work in my hands.

Pleae help me wrte this PHP crypt procedure in Delphi.
NB! ecb is madatory.

Harry Kalma

```
?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$qkey = hex2bin("58E5B91D04E43502683135770530BA86");
$qkeyver = chr(0x01);

$QRcode =  qencrypt($qkey, $qkeyver) ; //generates QR code string
print qdecrypt($QRcode, $qkey) . "</br>"; //decrypts QR code string

function qdecrypt($token, $key)
{
        echo $token . "<br />\n";
        echo bin2hex($token) . "<br />\n";
        $token = str_replace("-", "+", $token);
        $token = str_replace("_", "/", $token);
        $p = strlen($token) % 3;
        //base64 padding fix
            while ($p > 1) {
        $token = $token . "=";
        $p--;
        $token = base64_decode($token);
    }
    $token = substr($token, 1); //removing key number
    return openssl_decrypt($token, "aes-128-ecb", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
}


function qencrypt($key, $keyver)
{
        $message = "LR12;15;41e33b9";
        $token   = openssl_encrypt($message, "aes-128-ecb", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
        //echo $token;
        $token   = $keyver . $token;
        $token   = base64_encode($token);
        $token   = str_replace("+", "-", $token); //make url valid
        $token   = str_replace("/", "_", $token); //make url valid
        $token   = rtrim($token, "=");
        return $token;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I suggest you give a look at the C source code of PHP function openssl_encrypt() which can be found at https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/openssl/openssl.c#L7090 Then look at a Delphi wrapper for OpenSSL API and translate PHP C source code to Delphi. If you have some difficulty doing that translation, open a new specific question, showing the code you managed to write and telling what you can't do.

Comment: There is no need to use a wrapper for OpenSSL. AES128 ECB is a standard algorithm, it's not specific to OpenSSL.

Comment: @Olivier Maybe the argument "aes-128-ecb" in PHP code is just an example. Using OpenSSL wrapper will handle everything that PHP does. OpenSSL is well documented and the OP already has PHP code calling OpenSSL do do exactly what he needs. So I think it is easier to use OpenSSL than using other libraries.